# Call C++ programs from C# /WPF

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

Can someone point me to a full example of how to run compiled C++ programs (executables) from C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to launch the .exe, as if someone ran it from the command prompt?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Comment: [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is like that:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

try
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // You can start any process; HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.Start();
    // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
    // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
    // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
    // from this application using the Kill method.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```